# ngTemplateOutlet: Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When using ngTemplateOutlet and context:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: Context"></ng-container>
```

The context data:

```
this.Context = {
        $implicit: this.userName,
        'password': this.password,
        'Login': this.Login,
        'Register': this.Register
    };
```

can't be bound to a 2 way binding, is this a limitation or am i doing something wrong?

```
<ng-template let-username #loginpage> 
<TextField class="input" hint="Email" keyboardType="email" [(ngModel)]="username"></TextField> 
</ng-template>
```

I am getting this error:

> ns-renderer: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Comment: Please add more code. Where do you use ngModel?

Comment: I am using it inside the template. As you can see in the modified post.

Comment: `ngModel` can't assign to local variables. You can only assign to properties (fields) of your component https://plnkr.co/edit/xlZgPVU2UQnVg4uoeKvj?p=preview

Comment: Okey, well this doesn't work for me since i am using a component that takes a input: @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>; so i can't access the public variable from the Context.
Like this:
<login [template]="loginpage" (login)="Login($event)"></login>

Comment: I've similar problem, i reproduce it https://angular-hhxgth.stackblitz.io